# Algorithm using for searching in Dart

Tags: algorithm, dart

What is the specific name of algorithm used for string searching (specifically contains method) in Dart programming language? I tried to find on the [SDK](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/b86c6e0ce93e635e3434935e31fac402bb094705/sdk/lib/collection/list.dart#L107-L116) and find these

```
  bool contains(Object element) {
    int length = this.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      if (this[i] == element) return true;
      if (length != this.length) {
        throw ConcurrentModificationError(this);
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

What is the name of the algorithm?

I actually wanted to know the details of the algorithm used in Dart

Comment: That is not s specific algorithm with a name. It is just comparing every object in the collection, one after another.

Comment: It's called a linear search: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search

Comment: @nvoigt So there is no name ? Every language should have the searching algorithm work in the backend